# Length of arc $ y = +\sqrt\frac{x^3 -4x^2 +4x}{6} $

Tags: solution-verification, arc-length

What is the length of the arc?
$$ y = +\sqrt\frac{x^3 -4x^2 +4x}{6}  $$ from $x = 2 $ to $ x =8$

I used the equation
$$ L(x) = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1+ (y')^2} dx$$
where my $ x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = 8 $.
My final answer is approximately 9.2. Is this correct?

Comment: In short: yes; it's approx. $9.2376$.

Comment: Thank you! But how come that the answer key says it is approximately 10.007?

Comment: The key must be wrong or you've mistyped the function. ;)  It's fairly easy to compute $L(x)=\frac{\sqrt 6}{6} \cdot\sqrt{x}(x+2)$.

Comment: As @Michael Hoppe wrote, the result is exactly $\frac{16}{\sqrt{3}} \sim  9.2376$